# Providing ":" operator for UDF std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a wrapper around an std::unorered_map however I am a little uncertain how I should provider a public member function to access the iteration provided by the ":" feature in C++11, for example:

```
//Iterate through all unoredered_map keys
for(auto x : my_map){
    //Process each x
}
```

How could I provide the same capability as above, via my wrapper around the `unordered_map`?

Tried solution:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T, typename K>
class MyClass{
private:
    std::unordered_map<T,K> map;
    std::mutex mtx;

public:

    MyClass(){}

    MyClass<T,K>(const MyClass<T,K>& src){
        //Going to lock the mutex
    }

    void insert(T key, K value){
        mtx.lock();
        map[T] = K;
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    K operator[](T key) const
    {
        return map[key];
    }

    K get(T key){
        return map[T];
    }

    decltype(map.cbegin()) begin() const 
    { 
        return map.begin(); 
    }

    decltype(map.cend()) end() const { 
        return map.end(); 
    }

    bool count(T key){
        int result = false;
        mtx.lock();
        result = map.count(key);
        mtx.unlock();
        return result;
    }

};
```

Comment: Use lockguard instead of manual `lock` and `unlock`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just provide `begin()` and `end()` methods, returning suitable iterators.

Here's an working example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct Foo
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;
  auto begin() const ->decltype(m.cbegin()) { return m.begin(); }
  auto end()   const ->decltype(m.cend())   { return m.end(); }

};


int main()
{
  Foo f{ { {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c",3} } };

  for (const auto& p : f)
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [more details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) how the `range-based for` is defined.

Comment: Does it not work if I put the unordered_map data member within a template class? I get this error: "error C2228: left of '.cend' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: You would have to post a *minimal* example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Strange. I thought due to the implicit `this` in the class-member-access, one had to put the `m.cbegin()` in a trailing-return-type. However, both g++4.8.1 and clang++3.5 don't complain.

Comment: Seems that's only required for non-static member *functions*, but not non-static data members. I.e. `struct Foo { int bar(); auto meow() -> decltype(bar()); };` because of the implicit `(*this)` inside the `decltype`. However `struct Foo { int bar; decltype(bar) meow(); };` is fine.

Comment: @user997112 after removing the irrelevant parts of your code, I cannot reproduce the problem. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/5Tm9zT).

Comment: @dyp Good point. I have to go and think about this. Does this agree with the standard?

Comment: @juanchopanza Well there's a special paragraph about nonstatic member functions where the transformation that introduces the implicit `(*this)` is described [class.mfct.non-static]/3; however I can't find anything corresponding for nonstatic data members. It's interesting that the return type of `decltype(m.begin()) begin() const;` might only known after reading the cv- and ref-qualifiers. (Maybe this has to do with the special treatment of id-expressions in `decltype`?)

Comment: @dyp I have reverted to the trailing return type syntax because at least there is no source of confusion there. I will have to look into this later.

Comment: @juanchopanza That'd be great. Maybe I'll even ask a question about it.

Comment: @user997112 Can you try again with the trailing return syntax (see my edit?)

Comment: It seems that in VS2012 if you declare the data member as being templated, the IDE/compiler doesn't allow you to select all the normal unordered_map member functions.... I created a std::set<double> and a std::set<T>. The former allowed me to choose cbegin(), the latter didnt....

Comment: @juanchopanza On rather recent g++4.9 and clang++3.5, both versions compile (trailing return type and "leading" return type). Even `decltype((m.begin())) begin() const;`, so it's not (only) the special `decltype` rules.

Comment: I accepted because I just removed the templates for the time being- but if anyone could provide a templated class answer would be most appreciated.

Comment: @user997112 It seems you need a solution for your particular compiler, which seems to be buggy in this respect.